# Is it possible for the Solidity compiler to remove an external call?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, assembly, yul

I am experiencing a weird situation where it seems that the Solidity compiler (or optimizer) is removing an external call.

I am performing an ERC20 token transfer on forked mainnet using Hardhat. From within a Hardhat unit test I check that the tokens were correctly transferred after the transaction executed. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
// Solidity version 0.8.4

let SIG_TRANSFER := 0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
let RECIPIENT_ADDR := 0xabc...
let TOKEN_ADDR := 0xdef...
let WITHDRAW_AMOUNT := 1000000000000000000

let free_mem_ptr := mload(0x40)
mstore(free_mem_ptr, SIG_TRANSFER) // transfer(address,uint256) function signature
mstore(add(free_mem_ptr, 0x4), RECIPIENT_ADDR) // recipient address
mstore(add(free_mem_ptr, 0x24), WITHDRAW_AMOUNT) // amount to transfer
let r := call(gas(), TOKEN_ADDR, 0x0, free_mem_ptr, 0x44, 0x0, 0x0)
if eq(r, 0x0) {
    revert(0, 0)
}
```

This code works as expected, and when I run it the tokens get transferred. **The `revert()` is not executed**, meaning the `call` succeeded. Interestingly however, if I comment-out the `revert`, i.e.

```
...
if eq(r, 0x0) {
    //revert(0, 0)
}
...
```

the transaction still succeeds but the token balances have not changed. Since during the first run the `revert` did not get executed, the `call()` must stil have been successful since it was not changed in any way.

What is happening here? Is the compiler/optimizer removing my `call` because I am not using the return value? The same thing also happens with `pop`:

```
pop(call(gas(), TOKEN_ADDR, 0x0, free_mem_ptr, 0x44, 0x0, 0x0))
```

Comment: Are you doing that in inline assembly within a Solidity contract or in pure Yul?

Comment: It's inline assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is impossible but if the `CALL` in your example actually got removed, it would be a bug in the compiler.

The only case I'm aware of where the compiler (I mean specifically the code generator) might skip emitting code is if you have an internal function that never gets called. The function as a whole is removed though, not individual instructions.

As for the optimizer (which can modify already emitted code), it [does have a set of annotations for builtins, one of which is `canBeRemoved`](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.8.10/libyul/SideEffects.h#L48-L78) but only [the ones with no side effects get this annotation](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.8.10/libevmasm/SemanticInformation.cpp#L222-L228) - `CALL` is definitely not one of them.

You can check if the instruction actually gets removed by inspecting the `--asm` output (see [Analysing the Compiler Output](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/analysing-compilation-output.html)). It's a direct rendering of the bytecode in a human-readable assembly form so if the instruction is there, it must be present in your compiled contract as well.

> The revert() is not executed, meaning the call succeeded.

That's unfortunately not always true. There's an important gotcha that you need to be aware of when making a low-level call (from [Units and Globally Available Variables > Members of Address Types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html)):

> Due to the fact that the EVM considers a call to a non-existing contract to always succeed, Solidity includes an extra check using the `extcodesize` opcode when performing external calls. This ensures that the contract that is about to be called either actually exists (it contains code) or an exception is raised.
>
> The low-level calls which operate on addresses rather than contract instances (i.e. `.call()`, `.delegatecall()`, `.staticcall()`, `.send()` and `.transfer()`) do not include this check, which makes them cheaper in terms of gas but also less safe.

Are you 100% sure that a contract actually exists at the target address? You said the tokens got transferred so I guess it does but it might be worth double-checking. You can add `EXTCODESIZE` to your code to verify that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I checked the assembly and in fact the `call` did *not* get removed. I assume it's a bug in Hardhat. The target contract definitely exists since I call the WETH address on forked mainnet (`0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`)